# Виртуальные методы

Tags: c++, классы

Можно ли вызывать виртуальные методы в конструкторах и деструкторах классов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Но **не рекомендуется**.

При вызове виртуального метода в конструкторе, будет вызвана функция (пере)определенная в этом классе, и одном из его базовых классов, но не в классах потомках, т.к. они еще не сконструированы.

В деструкторе происходит то же самое, класс-потомок уже разрушен, и его функции не могут быть вызваны. Поэтому будет вызована функция, определенная в этом классе или его базовых классах.

```
struct A {
  virtual void f() = 0;
  virtual void g() { std::cout << "A::g "; }
};

struct B : A {
  B() {
    f(); // будет вызвана B::f
    g(); // будет вызвана A::g
  }
  void f() override { std::cout << "B::f "; }
};

struct C : B {
  // не будут вызваны из конструктора B
  void f() override { std::cout << "C::f "; }
  void g() override { std::cout << "C::g "; }
};

C c; // выведет B::f A::g
```

Релевантная цитата из стандарта, [`12.7 Construction and destruction [class.cdtor] p4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#4):

> Member functions, including virtual functions (10.3), can be called during construction or destruction [...] If the virtual function call uses an explicit class member access (5.2.5) and the object expression refers to the complete object of x or one of that object’s base class subobjects but not x or one of its base class subobjects, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Эээ... вы уверены, что будет сделан _невиртуальный_ вызов? Если у меня есть class Base -> class Derived -> class MoreDerived, и они определяют виртуальный метод `f`, и `Derived::Derived` в конструкторе пишет `((Base*)this)->f()` — вы утверждаете, что будет вызван таки `Base::f`?

Comment: Насколько я помню, виртуальный вызов работает как виртуальный вызов, но во время пробега конструктора типа `Derived`, вызванного из конструктора `MoreDerived`, «мгновенным» типом объекта есть `Derived`, и будут вызваны его виртуальные методы.

Comment: Иллюстрация: http://ideone.com/4v9N3X

Comment: И вам спасибо! Вопрос очень важный, кстати (и ответ).